# How to test new version of a mobile app that had installed previously

Tags: android, ios, testing, mobile

I had previously launched an app on both Google Play store and app store.

During the initial release process, few of my friends helped me test my app via internal testing for android users and testflight for iOS users.

After successful release, I continued working on my updated version, and now I have everything set up except testing.

For now, I have uploaded new version of an app on internal testing(android), testflight(iOS), and wait for further process.

What I am wondering about is that testers(my friends, in this case) had downloaded previously released version and they still can download and test newer version of my app.

To sum up, here are things I want to know.

1. Can people whom I listed previously as testers and had downloaded previous release version of my app still download and use newer version of an app for testing?
2. I found out that this process is considered as QA(Testing). How mobile app testing on physical devices be done in companies?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

InternalTesting (on Google), same thing as TestFlight (on Apple), is done by sending invitations, so just remove relative Google/Apple account from their address lists and they cannot download updates and neither the App again.

The second point is not clear: what do you want to know exactly?